# It's correct $|e^{-R^{2}i \sin(\alpha)}| = e^{-R^{2}\sin(\alpha)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am a bit confusing about one step, I have simple:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}|e^{-R^2 i \sin(\alpha)}| \, d\alpha = \int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-R^2\sin(\alpha)} \, d\alpha$$

it's correct?

I think that we have only $$\int_0^{\pi/2}|e^{-R^2 i \sin(\alpha)}| \, d\alpha \leq \int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-R^2 \sin(\alpha)} \, d\alpha$$
because $|e^{-R^2 i \sin(\alpha)}| = 1$

Comment: If $R$ and $\alpha$ are real, that's not correct, since, as you say, $|\exp(-R^2i\sin\alpha)|=1$

Comment: We don't interpreter this exponent as number from circle where $\beta = -R^{2}sin(\alpha)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that

$$z=|z|e^{i\theta}$$

therfore assuming $R^2 \sin(\alpha) \in \mathbb R$

$$\left|e^{-R^{2}i \sin(\alpha)}\right| = 1 \implies \int_0^{\pi/2}\left|e^{-R^{2}i \sin(\alpha)}\right| d\alpha =\int_0^{\pi/2}1\, d\alpha =\frac \pi 2$$